# active voice and passive voice in the infinitive construction

Tags: infinitives

Here are two sentences:

> That is an interesting question to answer.
>
> It is an easy sentence to translate.

I am very confused about why we should use the active voice rather than the passive voice. Why couldn't we say this instead?

> That is an interesting question to be answered.
>
> It is an easy sentence to be translated.

Comment: Who says you should?

Comment: Could you rephrase that, at least for clarity? Thus far, it reads as more constructed than experienced…

Answer (score 3):

The active sentences here have an unexpressed subject for the verb phrases *to answer* and *to translate* - at least semantically. They mean something along the lines of:

- That is an interesting question (for someone) to answer.
- That's an easy sentence (for someone) to translate.

In some theories of grammar, they would actually stipulate that there is an actual non-overt pronoun in the space where the brackets are in the examples above. It has the flavour of a non-definite third person pronoun. Note that if we actually stipulate specific subjects for these verbs we are obliged to use the subordinator ***for***:

- That's an interesting question *for Bob* to answer.
- That's an easy sentence *for her* to translate.

This omission of subjects in constructions using *to*-infinitives is quite common. Compare the following pairs of sentences:

- I want *him* to leave.
- I want *it* to continue.

and now:

- I want __ to leave.
- He wants __ to continue.

This invites the question *who* do you want to leave? Or *Who* do you want to continue? The subject of the verb phrases *to leave, to continue* seems to be the same as the subject of the verb *want*. The last two sentences could be illustrated thus:

- I want (*myself*) to leave.
- He wants (*himself*) to continue.

These examples seem to show that infinitival clauses without *overt* subjects are still interpreted as semantically having subjects.

The passive sentences referred to in the question are a bit ambiguous to me. I'm not sure if I'm actually able to read them as the same type of sentence as the others. The *to* here seems to have a modal flavour. They seem to be the same type of sentence as:

- That is a question to be answered.
- That is a sentence to be translated.

The use of the infinitive here seems to imply that someone *ought to* answer the question or translate the sentence. It is perhaps this ambiguity which prevents the general use of the first constructions in the passive.

Answer (score 0):

Either might be used, depending upon the context. The active voice versions have at least a connotation that the speaker (or writer) is going to proceed to answer the question or translate the sentence; the passive voice versions imply that someone other than the speaker or writer might answer the interesting question, or translate the easy sentence.

In informal usage, I suspect the active voice would be a bit more common because it's shorter (in these cases, by two syllables each).