# a grammar question : to be in adjective clause

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Please explain the grammar of this sentence:

> *She was the first woman to be nominated for the national prize*.

Why do we use "to be" here? And is it *necessary?*

Comment: You should be aware that in English it is customary to begin sentences with capital letters. It is important to get the basics right before moving on to the more advanced stuff. In the sentence you quote *to be* is optional. It would make just as much grammatical sense if you left it out. Whichever of those two wordings that you use, idiomatically it describes a past event. That is determined by the second word of the sentence -  *was*. Change that to *will be* and the *to be* becomes obligatory, and the whole indicates something that is going to happen in the (most likely near) future.

Comment: Astonishingly, we don't seem to have any earlier questions on this specific aspect of usage (but *please* feel free to prove me wrong! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [active voice and passive voice in the infinitive construction](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/176970/active-voice-and-passive-voice-in-the-infinitive-construction)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: How can you call that a duplicate? That question is not about *to be*, which is what the OP is asking about specifically.

Comment: @Cerberus 'to be nominated': passive infinitive construction.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes, but somehow this sometimes behaves differently when connected with a noun phrase. The same applies to an active infinitive with *to*, by the way. *The way to do this, the child to punish*.

Comment: The article on [**Relative infinitive clauses** at Random Idea English by Warsaw Will](http://random-idea-english.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/relative-infinitive-clauses-uses-and.html) explains this in great depth, but this question is obviously a duplicate so I won't post an answer from the article here.

Comment: Considering the number of comments and disagreements this question has generated, why is it "off-topic"? If even experienced experts are in disagreement, doesn't it suggest that the answer is not to be found in a dictionary? (Or Wikipedia)

Answer (score 1):

**In the sentence you quote *to be* is optional. It would make just as much grammatical sense if you left it out.**

Whichever of those two wordings that you use, idiomatically it describes a past event. That is determined by the second word of the sentence -  *was*. Change that to *will be* and the *to be* becomes more likely to be included, and the whole indicates something that is going to happen in the (near) future.

Comment: You might consider knocking out that first paragraph at some point, and perhaps add that ***who was*** would be a syntactically valid alternative to ***to be*** (or, as you say, nothing at all). I assume that would help OP, given he suggests the ungrammatical alternative *first woman **whom** nominated*.

Comment: Taking note of your final sentence, would you therefore say [*Judi will be the first woman ordained to the priesthood at All Saints*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Judi+will+be+the+first+woman%22) is "ungrammatical"? It seems fine to me, but I'm not sure if it's trampling over some specific "rule" that I'm simply unaware of. Not that I'd be inclined to respect any such rule (I'd doubtless just dismiss it as "pedantry", on the grounds that *others* don't respect it either). But I'd be interested to know if a relevant rule/principle exists at all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, you are right. I am going to change the word *obligatory* to *more likely*.

Comment: Considering how many rubbish questions we get on ELU that *aren't* closed, it's a bit disappointing to see this one *has* been (I might appeal on Meta if it's not reopened in a day or two). I think your edit accurately reflects usage, in that we probably *are* more likely to include ***to be*** in "future-based" assertions of this type. But it might be interesting to know more about *why* this is so, and whether there are exceptions. Also, what about *Judi will be the first woman **giving** absolution to men at All Saints* (which I *think* is "okay", but maybe not everyone would agree)?

Answer (score 1):

In English, as in many European languages, the infinitive can be used to express *expectation* when it modifies an adjective or noun. The preposition/particle *to* is used to connect the infinitive with the noun or adjective.

> The work was to be done by her mother.

This means "it was expected that her mother would do the work". The phrase *to be done by her mother* modifies *the work*, it tells us that there is the expectation of a certain action and that the noun phrase *the work* is the 'subject' of the action. (That is, the noun phrase performs the semantic role that is normally performed by the subject of the verb/predicate used in this infinitive phrase.)

> She is the first woman to be nominated for the national prize.

This should mean: "it is expected that someone will nominate the first woman for the national prize, and she is that first woman." However, the sense of expectation from the infinitive is sometimes weakened, as in this example; the sentence means almost the same thing as *she is the first woman (who was) nominated for the national prize*. As you see, the infinitive was almost devoid of meaning here. But perhaps this can still be explained away as a kind of implicit expectation: I'm pondering it.

Comment: But in this case, it doesn't express expectation. It's just a plain infinitive. Consider: *She swam the English channel.* can be turned into *She was the first worman to swim the English channel. *She was nominated for the national prize* turns into *She was the first woman nominated for the national prize.*

Comment: @PeterShor: Yes, this is a weakened form of the infinitive of expectation, and I don't recommend it. Its origin is the infinitive of expectation, though, which is why I thought it essential to explain how that construction worked. See the final paragraph of my answer.

Comment: A little searching of Google books shows that this "weakened" construction has been around for over 200 years. Would you still call it non-traditional?

Comment: @PeterShor: I'll have to think about it, perhaps I was too hasty. Perhaps the "weak" sense can be explained away as an expectation after all, in that the time of utterance is just before she was nominated, or that it was only established afterwards that she was the first—something like that. Do you agree that this is weird?: *she became the first woman to be nominated*. This sounds redundant to me, probably because both *became* and *to be* suggest something about the future.

Comment: Maybe it is a weakened form of an infinitive of expectation, but it was weakened a long time ago. Or maybe there's a different explanation for the grammar. It's an interesting question.

Comment: @Peter Shor It's just a passive clause.

Comment: In your example _the work was to be done by her mother_, isn't this a **passive clause** with "the work" as subject and the VP _to be done by her mother_ as predicate? If it was modifying the NP "the work" simply to form a larger NP, there would be no main verb in the sentence. But in something like _The work done by her mother_, then the past-participial clause would indeed be a modifier (with a passive interpretation)

Comment: @BillJ: Yes, it is a full clause. But that doesn't mean the *to be done* phrase doesn't modify the noun phrase *the work*: you could say it doesn't modify it *directly*, but the copula *was* couples subject and subject complement such that one is modified by the other. At any rate, you can change it into a noun phrase if you like: *the work to be done by her mother*. That doesn't change anything about the expectation expressed in [*to* + inf. modifying a noun phrase], does it? // It is indeed passive because of *done*, but why do you mention that?

Comment: I didn't say that in your example _to be done_ modifies the NP _the work_. I actually said the opposite. In something like _the work to be done by her mother is extensive_, then the sub clause _to be done by her mother_ is modifier of _the work_ , but in _The work was to be done by her mother_, it's the predicate. There's no complement, no copula, in either sentence. "Was" is just the past form of "be" required here to form a passive clause in my 2nd example.

Comment: To be clear, what I'm saying is that in _The work was to be done by her mother_, the phrase _to be done by her mother_ is not modifying the NP _the work_, but is part of the passive predicate of the clause _The work was to be done by her mother_, in which _the work_ is subject, **not** head of a noun phrase.

Comment: 'She is the first woman to be nominated for the national prize.' and 'She is  to be nominated for the national prize.' are entirely different constructions.

Comment: @BillJ: I know you said the opposite, which is why we disagree. // As to you last analysis, I don't disagree with that, but it does not conflict with mine. // At any rate, it doesn't matter, because none of this is essential to my answer, it's a red herring. Change my example into *the work to be done by her mother*. My answer works perfectly well with that.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth See my previous comment. Those are different constructions, but the relevant part is the same, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: So, as the deleted form 'She is/was the first woman nominated for the national prize.' has lost the 'relevant part', it suddenly _does_ matter? This analysis is incorrect. The idiom 'be to be V'd' is totally different from a passivised nominal complement 'be / become the first woman to be V'd'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Umm I don't understand your comment at all. Why do you mention that sentence without *to be*? What analysis? Why are the last two things different? *To be* indicates, or should indicate, a sense of expectation in both cases.

Comment: 'She was the first woman nominated for the national prize.' and 'She was the first woman to be nominated for the national prize.' are strictly synonymous. Along with 'She was the first woman who was nominated for the national prize.' No sense of expectation involved. Just post-modification using a passive (implicit in the first example).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: 1. I said "almost the same thing". Are you dissatisfied with that somehow? 2. I think you're being a little bit too quick in saying that there is no expectation. You may realise that there is some sense of expectation in it after pondering it for a while. Or not. I'm not 100% sure myself. But this is a complicated matter. For example, the hypothetical time of utterance may have shifted, making this an expectation as seen from an earlier point in time. The shift may nullify this expectation, but that doesn't mean they can't still both be present. Or something like that.

Comment: "Aeschylus, the great Athenian author of tragedies, was the first man to be killed by a tortoise."  Only to be expected.